# How to remove permission for flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter

Please update your app so that the feature uses Media Store APIs and remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

This is the reason i dont know what can be done in this situation .i am using read and write permission along with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but my app got rejected again and again and i have also mentioned the reason to use this permission to download files.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Android version 12 , you face this issue as Google restrict some policy regarding storage, You must use below package for Storage Framework Access , With this usage your app won't rejected :)

[SAF](https://pub.dev/packages/saf)

Comment: is this package is best to replace with the path provider which i m using now , then do i need to add permissions for read and write and manage exterenal storage ?

Comment: Your current API level? below 20?

Comment: minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30